# Paint on UV'ed model with external editor

Tags: texturing, uv, image, external-applications

The thing is that the guide I'm following uses 3Dcoat to have the texture projected from the one side to the other side. I figured that Blender would be able to do this also, but I'm not quite sure how it works. I've tried to search the internet and there's probably guide, but I do really not know what to search for to find what I'm looking for.

Guide that I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiNASmArkxA

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help, I found what I was looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hb-OZTNFatw

Comment: Most of the painting functions from external software is available in blender, and symmetric painting will be available in version 2.75.

Answer (score 2):

UV unwap the object, enter edit mode, go to the UV editor, click UVs at the bottom and finally click Export UV layout. It will give you an image with a UV template image, which you can paint over and then load back into blender.

Update: Based on your comment, try cutting the object in half using K and deleted one half. Then use the mirror modifier to restore the other side. Then position the viewport in the position you would like the final 2D texture coordinates to be. Now go into edit mode, press U and then unwrap from view. Follow the remainder of my steps from there.

Comment: I don't know how to explain exactly what I mean, would be the easiest if you viewed the guide in the OP at around 10:20. What I'd like is to export a the 3d model as a 2d model where my work on one side gets duplicated to the other, if that makes any sense. I'm not looking for an UV map.

Comment: Updated my answer to hopefully answer your question.